# didn't pass LDFLAGS? [ldflags]

Tags: yocto, bitbake, openembedded

I created a recipe, summary as follows:

```
do_install() {
  install -d ${D}/GreenTea
  cp ${S}/foo.sh ${D}/GreenTea
  cp ${S}/foo.so ${D}/GreenTea
```

when bitbake this recipe, it shows:     didn't pass LDFLAGS? [ldflags]

```
ERROR: greentea-1.0-r0 do_package_qa: QA Issue: No GNU_HASH in the ELF binary /home/tea/greentea4/build/tmp/work/corei7-64-poky-linux/greentea/1.0-r0/packages-split/greentea/GreenTea/foo.so, didn't pass LDFLAGS? [ldflags]
```

What can I do?

Comment: Yocto sets LDFLAGS to be used during linking of foo.so. The QA test found evidence that this did not happen. Typical build systems respect LDFLAGS and everything just works... so the question is, how do you build/link your foo.so?

Comment: It is a pre-build so file, not bitbake run time generated.

Comment: @JussiKukkonen so how should I modify my build system so that everything works if I'm building my own SO image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can [skip](https://docs.yoctoproject.org/ref-manual/variables.html#term-INSANE_SKIP) the warning:

```
INSANE_SKIP:${PN} += "ldflags"

# when this question was originally asked the format was
INSANE_SKIP_${PN} += "ldflags"
```

This does not mean the library will actually work on target (the QA warnings are there for a reason) but it will allow packaging to continue. The dev-manual now has a whole section about [Pre-built binaries](https://docs.yoctoproject.org/dev-manual/prebuilt-libraries.html).

Answer (score 9):

If you're compiling the source for yourself, you should not skip the `LDFLAGS` warning as mentioned by [@jussi-kukkonen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2241569/jussi-kukkonen) and you should add the following line in your Yocto recipe

```
TARGET_CC_ARCH += "${LDFLAGS}"
```

Ref: [How to fix : ERROR: do_package_qa: QA Issue: No GNU_HASH in the elf binary](https://lynxbee.com/how-to-fix-error-do_package_qa-qa-issue-no-gnu_hash-in-the-elf-binary/)

Answer (score 1):

### Problem:

I encountered an issue during the build process of my Yocto recipe, specifically in the do_package_qa task. The error message in the log indicated:

```
ERROR: QA Issue: File /usr/bin/Hello_World in package helloworld doesn't have GNU_HASH (didn't pass LDFLAGS?) [ldflags]
ERROR: Fatal QA errors were found, failing task.
```

### Explanation:

During the do_package_qa task, Yocto performs a set of tests to ensure that the built software meets certain standards and packaging guidelines. In my case, the error was related to the absence of the GNU_HASH, indicating that the --hash-style=gnu option wasn't passed to the linker during compilation.

### Solution:

To resolve this issue, you need to ensure that the --hash-style=gnu option is passed to the linker during the compilation process. In the do_compile section of your recipe, add the following line:

```
do_compile () {
     ${CXX} *.cpp -o Application_Name -Wl,--hash-style=gnu
}
```

This option instructs the linker to use the GNU-style hash table, which is crucial for systems utilizing the GNU C Library (glibc). It improves symbol lookup performance and ensures compatibility.

By adding this line to your recipe, you should address the GNU_HASH-related QA issue during the Yocto build process.